# Gulp task not recognizing 'sass', "Gem undefined not installed"

Tags: ruby, npm, sass, gulp

When running a task in Gulp I get the error below:

[image]

I have seen other posts and already made sure the ruby bin path was added to system path variable, but that didn't seem to make any difference, even after rebooting my whole computer. I also checked to see what gems are installed from command line and Sass is there:

[image]

And what is extra weird is it seems the 'scss' task that actually uses gulp-ruby-sass runs fine earlier on?

The only thing is that even with Ruby and Sass installed on my machine I have to be in the ruby bin directory to use it, it's not globally available on my machine, and maybe that is the problem?

Comment: the sass command compiles sass files into css files. Sounds like you need to add the path of sass to your PATH env variable.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install Sass:

1. Install Ruby on your machine [Download Link](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)
2. Add ruby bin folder path to path user and system variable
3. Open the command prompt in your system and install sass globally so you don't need to be in the ruby folder using the following command:

   gem install sass